# What's the lifetime of an object using SignalR with Unity Dependency Resolver?

Tags: asp.net, linq-to-sql, signalr, unity-container

Let me start with a little setup info... I am using the repository pattern and dependency injection via Unity. The repository is implemented via Linq-To-Sql. I inject my repositories into class constructors in my web project. The repositories have a `PerWebRequest` lifetime.

I have implemented a few SignalR hubs and have setup a Unity dependency resolver for SignalR. I'm injecting the same repositories into the hubs using the *same* Unity config file, which specifies these repositories are `PerWebRequest` also.

Now the punchline... I ran into a problem where the web project would update an Linq-To-Sql entity and the SignalR hub would read that entity and not get the updates. I have "solved" this problem by clearing the Linq-To-Sql cache before reading the entity in the SignalR hub; `DataContact.Refresh()` didn't update the entire object graph.

My `DataContext` for these repositories used in hubs are also `PerWebRequest` but it seams that the SignalR hubs are using a separate `DataContext` that does not get destroyed after the web request completes. It appears they are acting as singleton instances instead.

Do SignalR apps run in their own process and therefore my `DataContext` access from the hubs is a separate `DataContext` in that separate process?

How could the `DataContext` in the SignalR hub be instantiated with a `PerWebRequest` lifetime if it a separate process, apart from the web request lifecycle? Also, how does it seemingly act like a Singleton?

Answer (score 0):

It's a while I don't use stuff like `Linq2Sql` or concepts like `PerWebRequest`, so I'm not 100% sure, but if I'm correct in saying that `PerWebRequest` is definitely tied to the lifetime of underlying HTTP requests, then those will hardly work with SignalR because its behavior can change a lot according to the chosen transport strategy. With WebSockets you might have several hub instantiations/method calls over the same connection, while with Long Polling you would probably have one (or zero) per HTTP request. Check [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/guide-to-the-api/handling-connection-lifetime-events) and [here](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr#transports).

Given that the code you write with SignalR should be the same regardless of the transport, I think for hubs you'd always have to handle repositories in a specific way, maybe with an ad-hoc factory always clearing the cache each time a repository has to be supplied to a SignalR hub (you could try to be smart and check the transport strategy used, but those could be muddy waters).